# Insert Into con filtro para solo 1 campo

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

Mi código actual es el siguiente.

```
INSERT INTO Avisado
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Filtro
WHERE Artículo NOT IN(SELECT Empresa FROM Avisado)
```

En el codigo estoy intentando insertar en la tabla Avisado registros no repetidos (Empresas que han comprado nuevos productos).
Mi objetivo final es el siguiente: Tengo 2 tablas con los mismos campos, mismo nombre de 'empresa'. La finalidad era insertar en una tabla todos los registros de lo que seria una nueva compra. Es decir, que esa 'empresa' no haya comprado ese Artículo en concreto, para así evitar compras repetidas, lo que intento evitar con la consulta es a la hora de insertar que solamente se encuentren los nuevos registros con empresas que hayan comprado nuevos productos. He probado de varias formas, todas sin éxito. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, ya que me estoy iniciando en todo esto.
Un saludo.

A continuación os pongo un ejemplo de que es lo que estoy intentando realizar. Tengo 2 tablas que seria las siguientes

Tabla1

```
Empresa1 - Tomate
Empresa1 - Cebolla
Empresa1 - Lechuga
Empresa2 - Manzana
Empresa2 - Tomate
Empresa2 - Lechuga
```

Tabla2

```
Empresa1 - Tomate
Empresa1 - Manzana
Empresa1 - Lechuga
Empresa2 - Manzana
Empresa2 - Tomate
Empresa2 - Zanahoria
```

El objetivo final seria insertar la tabla2 en la 1 para que quedara al final sin repetidos.
El resultado seria así:
Tabla1

```
Empresa1 - Tomate
**Empresa1 - Manzana**
Empresa1 - Cebolla
Empresa1 - Lechuga
Empresa2 - Manzana
Empresa2 - Tomate
**Empresa2 - Zanahoria**
Empresa2 - Lechuga
```

Comment: Hola, te sugiero leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), ademas puedes pasarte por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y ganar tu primera medalla ;)

Comment: Por favor agrega un poco mas de información acerca de tu problema, tal vez las estructuras de esas tablas y explicar un poco que intentas hacer en esa consulta que colocaste allí

Comment: El objetivo final de la consulta era insertar en una de las tablas las compras de nuevos productos de esa empresa. Lo que quiero evitar es que de una empresa se inserte el registro de una compra de un producto que ya se había comprado anteriormente. No sé si me estoy explicando correctamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No es la solución más elegante, pero puedes hacerlo con 3 consultas en Microsoft Access (Aunque seguro que hay una forma mejor).

Lo primero, he recreado tus tablas de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después, he creado 3 consultas:

1. La primera consulta crea una clave única concatenando Empresa y Producto, uniendo ambas tablas con el siguiente código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT [Empresa] & [Producto] AS Expr1, EMPRESA, PRODUCTO
FROM Tabla1
UNION ALL SELECT [Empresa] & [Producto] AS Expr1, EMPRESA, PRODUCTO
FROM Tabla2;
```

1. La segunda consulta es igual que la anterior, pero solo de la tabla 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT [Empresa] & [Producto] AS Expr1, Tabla1.Empresa, Tabla1.Producto
FROM Tabla1;
```

1. La tercera es la consulta que busca **no coincidentes** entre las dos consultas anteriores y las inserta en la tabla 1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
INSERT INTO Tabla1 ( EMPRESA, PRODUCTO )
SELECT Consulta1.EMPRESA, Consulta1.PRODUCTO
FROM Consulta1 LEFT JOIN Consulta2 ON Consulta1.[Expr1] = Consulta2.[Expr1]
WHERE (((Consulta2.Expr1) Is Null));
```

Cuando ejecuto la consulta 3 obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De todas formas he subido un ejemplo a Google Drive por si quieres descargarlo y cotillear las consultas: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LhPfJvmQA5rV3NjP0P5FTD-Li6-z0zDf/view?usp=sharing